# Is there a Java in-process database, wich allows access from multible VMs?

Tags: java, database, virtual-machine, sqljet

I am looking for a library which allows to run an in-process database like SQLJet, but it has to be accessible from multiple vms (on the same machine) simultaneously like an independent database server.
At best something like this: You create a new file-system database, then open a connection to it from one vm. If you then try to do the same thing from a different vm, it checks if theres already a connection to it and syncs with it.
If there's no such thing, any ideas how i can run a in-process database server in java? Doesnt have to be sql, mongoDB or any database system will do. The important part is, that i do not have to run a seperate database engine, but it has to be accessible from multiple vms.

Comment: Did you try Apache Derby aka Java DB? Which allows both Embedded as well as Remote Mode.

Comment: or maybe h2? http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html take a look at the mixed mode

Comment: Isn't "in-process" and "accessible from multiple VMs" a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [H2](http://www.h2database.com/) in [TCP server mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html). In one of your VMs start it like so:

```
 Server server = Server.createTcpServer(args).start();
```

Other VM can connect using JDBC:

```
JDBC driver class: org.h2.Driver
Database URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
```